# Unable to get node using xpath in soapUI

Tags: xml, soapui

How can i access "AccountId" node from following response file using Xpath in soapUI 4.0.0?

Thanks in advance.

Response file is as follow,

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetResponse xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/cmw/tcm/account">
         <GetResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Account>
               <AccountId>14338049839</AccountId>
               <AccountLabel>Spara Femman</AccountLabel>
               <AccountRoleDTOList>
                  <AccountRole>
                     <AddressTypeId>REC</AddressTypeId>
                     <EndDay i:nil="true"/>
                     <ExtPosReference i:nil="true"/>
                     <HolderId>10533</HolderId>
                     <HolderName>TÄRNHOLMS HOTELL AB</HolderName>
                     <HolderTypeId>COR</HolderTypeId>
                     <IdentificationId>005164006917</IdentificationId>
                     <ReportProfileId>3</ReportProfileId>
                     <ReportProfileName>Standard</ReportProfileName>
                     <RoleDocumentPath i:nil="true"/>
                     <RoleId>HOL</RoleId>
                     <RoleName>Holder</RoleName>
                     <ShareOfAccount>100.00000</ShareOfAccount>
                  </AccountRole>
               </AccountRoleDTOList>
               <AccountTypeId>AGG</AccountTypeId>
               <CloseDay i:nil="true"/>
               <CurrencyId>SEK</CurrencyId>
               <CustodianAccountId i:nil="true"/>
```

I have tried it by using following code... but it's not working

```
declare namespace i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
//i:GetResult[1]/Account[1]
```

But i am getting error like,
Missing content for xpath  declare namespace i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
//i:GetResult[1]/Account[1] in response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error getting a node on SOAP UI's test case XPATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831248/error-getting-a-node-on-soap-uis-test-case-xpath)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
declare namespace i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
//i:GetResult[1]/i:Account[1]
```

OR

```
declare namespace i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
//i:GetResult[1]/*:Account[1]
```