# Error getting a node on SOAP UI's test case XPATH

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, soapui

I had been stuck while  playing with the SOAP UI getting started tutorial because i can't  produce an assertion condition for a simple testing. I'm Using the XPATH method to test the following SOAP message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
         <GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
            <Success>false</Success>
            <ResponseText>City could not be found in our weather data. Please contact CDYNE for more Details.</ResponseText>
            <State/>
            <City/>
            <WeatherStationCity/>
            <WeatherID>-1</WeatherID>
            <Description/>
            <Temperature/>
            <RelativeHumidity/>
            <Wind/>
            <Pressure/>
            <Visibility/>
            <WindChill/>
            <Remarks/>
         </GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
      </GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using the following Xpath expression:

```
declare namespace i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
//i:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult[1]/i:Success[1]
```

and this is the error:

```
XPathContains assertion failed for path [declare namespace i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
//i:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult[1]/i:Success[1]] : Exception:Missing content for xpath [declare namespace i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
//i:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult[1]/i:Success[1]] in Response
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using defined namespaces in SoapUI XPath assertions unnecessarily complicates things, and in some cases outright does not work. Start with just `//*:GetCityWeatherByZIPResult/*:Success` for your XPath, and work up from there as needed.

Comment: I hate SoapUI so much for recommending the long complex namespace declaration in `Get Data` only to get confused by it later on. This worked